# Placing sich in relativsatz

Tags: reflexive

I have got 2 sentences here to translate them into German. I am not sure if I am doing it well:

*I know a lot of people who are afraid of the number 13.*

> Ich weiß viele Menschen, die sich vom Nummer 13 fürchten.

Here is another one

*I know a woman, whose hair I comb.*

> Ich weiß eine Frau, deren sich das Haar ich kämme.

Are these any good?

Have you got any resources on how to use the "sich-verben" in the nebensatz of relativsatz?

Comment: I corrected the mistake "Mänschen", because it is not related to the question about the placement of "sich". The correct spelling is "Menschen".

Comment: "to know" (without "of") in reference to people invariably means "kennen" in German. As this is not related to the question about placement of "sich", I'd thought I'll point this out in a comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Before adressing the *sich*-question, think about the following corrections:

*I know a lot of people who are afraid of the number 13.*

> Ich <s>weiß</s> **kenne** viele M**e**nschen, die sich vo**r** <s>Nummer</s> der Zahl 13 fürchten.

- it has to be *kennen* → *to be familiar with*.
- it has to be *die Zahl 13*. *Nummer 13* is a proper name for a specimen or issue of a periodical.
- *sich fürchten vor* takes the dative, but the gender of the article must match. It's both *die Nummer* and *die Zahl*. Also, shortening the *vor der* is not allowed here as the article is used as a lightweight demonstrative pronoun in this case.

The *sich* in contrary is placed correctly.

---

*I know a woman, whose hair I comb.*

> Ich <s>weiß</s> **kenne** eine Frau, deren <s>sich das</s> Haar ich kämme.

(No article for *Haar*. The relative pronoun *deren* already serves that purpose.)

**Who** combs the hair? The woman? No. It's you. Please consider

> **Ich** kenne eine Frau, deren Haar **ich** kämme.
>
> **Ich** kenne eine Frau, der **ich** das Haar kämme.

I comb the hair of the woman. No reflection at all.

> **Ich** kämme **mir** das Haar.

I comb **my own** hair. Reflection to the subject *ich* → *mir*.

> **Eine Frau** kämmt **sich** das Haar.

A woman combs **her own** hair. Reflection to the subject *Eine Frau* → *sich*.

> Ich kenne **eine Frau**, die **sich** das Haar kämmt.

The woman combs **her own** hair. Reflection to the accusative object *eine Frau* → *sich*

> **Ich** kenne eine Frau, die **mir** das Haar kämmt.

The woman combs my hair. No reflection but the dative of the personal pronoun *ich* → *mir*.

> Ich kenne eine Frau, die ihm/ihr das Haar kämmt.

The woman combs the hair of a third person. No reflection but the dative of the personal pronoun *er/sie/es* → *ihm/ihr/ihm*.

Comment: Du könntest noch "der ich das Haar kämme" erwähnen.

Comment: Habe ich nun als Abwandlung des ersten Beispiels eingefügt.

Comment: Also valid: *Ich kenne eine Frau, die ihr Haar kämmt* - no reflexive pronoun required here.